# Extending geodesics to vector fields

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $c$ be a geodesic on a Manifold $M$. Some books define $c$ to be a Geodesic iff $\nabla_{c'}c'=0$. 
Therefore for every $c(t)$ the Geodesic must be extendable into a smooth vector field on an open set of $c(t)$.

How can I prove this? Is this true for any smooth curve on M or just with geodesics?

Regards.

Comment: I'm not sure about what means extending a geodesic into a vector field. Geodesics are curves and not vector fields. Could you clarify please?

Comment: Ok no problem! I mean, one can find a (usual) Vector field X on M, s.t. X(c(t))=c'(t) $\forall t$. That is X is equal to the vector field c'(t) along c, but is also defined an an open set (like a coordinate nbhd.)

Comment: If you are working on borderless manifolds, it will be true for geodesics. You can try the following: for each $c(t)$, consider a totally convex neighborhood of $c(t)$ and a small coordinate chart defined on it in rrder to construct your desired vector field. I think it could work.

Comment: Why should this definition imply that every $c(t)$ admit such an extension? $\nabla_{c'}c'$ only depends on the values of $c'$ along the curve $c$ (just write down the formula in coordinates) so one does not need to extend $c'$ to make this definition meaningful.

Comment: @treble Extension is in tangent field original in the curve, does'nt refer to domain extension of the curve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you mean to *geodesic field* when your affine conection is compatible with you riemannian metric. It's always exists and existence follows directly from the differential equations defining the paralel transport of the tangent unitary map.

I dont know a direct counterexample when a smooth curve doesnt have this property, you must construct some curve such that any differentiable tangent field is forced to have some singular points. For example in $S^2$ there isn't a differentiable tangent field, because always you can find a singularity.

Comment: I think the field he is looking for is a field over a neighborhood of $c(t)$ in $M$. The geodesic field is a field on $TM$.

Comment: Differential equations given us the answer, the problem is about existence and it could be very hard to determine. If you curve have a tangent field not parallel to manifold, differentials equations may be quite hard and probably existence doesnt hold even in the curve (indeed a neighborhood of curve).

Answer (score 0):

Take the vector field and extend it via $d\exp_{c(t)}|_\nu$, where $\nu$ is the normal bundle over $c$.

The tangent bundle of $c$, $Tc$, resides in $TM|_c$.  The existence of a metric lets us pick out elements of $TM|_c$ *perpendicular* to $Tc$.  All such perpendicular elements form the *normal bundle* $\nu(c\subset M)$.  The exponential map takes a small neighborhood of the zero section of $\nu$ to a small open neighborhood of $c$.

If we have a vector field $X$ defined on $c$, we can extend it to a vector field on $\nu$, defined by extending it constantly on each fiber (note that $\dim\nu = \dim TM|_c$).  Now just push $X$ out to $\exp\nu$ by $d\exp$, which is a diffeomorphism.

Alternately, since $c$ is a submanifold, it has an atlas of coordinate charts which take the form $c\times \mathbb{R}^{n-1}$ (here $n = \dim M$).  You can extend $X$ to a neighborhood of $c$ by extending $X$ to a neighborhood of $c$ in each coordinate chart so that it commutes with the projection.  (You will need to be a little careful about coordinate changes, though.)

Answer (score 0):

Your comment

*Ok no problem! I mean, one can find a (usual) Vector field X on M, s.t. X(c(t))=c'(t) ∀t. That is X is equal to the vector field c'(t) along c, but is also defined an an open set (like a coordinate nbhd.)*

does not match your question: if $v\in T_pM$ is a tangent vector, then
$\nabla_v Y$ may be defined to be $\nabla_X Y$ for some locally defined vector field $X$ as long $X_p=v$. This is done pointwise, if $c(t)$ is a curve there is no need for a locally defined vector field $X$ having $X(c(t))=c'(t)$ **for all** $t$ (I think such an $X$ doesn't have to exist in an open nhood of $c(I)$ where $c:I\rightarrow M$ is a curve.

Comment: I think the statement of the question is just a little bit confused. I think it is not for *all* $t$, but just for a neighborhoof ot "t", or, we just have to find a *local* vector field.

Comment: I think $\nabla_vY$ makes sense even if $v$ is not $X(p)$ for a local vector field $X$. In the expression in coordinates of the covariant derivative, you have just to know $Y$ locally and $v$ in the point

Comment: *Therefore for every ... must be extendible* indicates that the OP uses a definition of $\nabla$ that depends on vector fields.

Comment: You mean $\nabla$ will depend of the choice of $c$ too?

Comment: No, $\nabla$ is given (the Levi-Civita-Connection) - the question is why you said that the tangent vector $c'(t)$ must be extendible to a nhood of $c(t)$ (for one/all $t$)?

Comment: If you fix a $t$, then in a neighborhood we have $c(t)$ embedded. You can suppose it is inside a coordinate chart and via this chart you can extend the vector field $c'(t)$ to $X$, but just locally. It will happen yet $\nabla_{\gamma'}X=0$ over $\gamma$, inside this neighborhood. Perhaps we are thinkink about different things so we are not convincing each other =)